# Calling the Data-Attribute of a Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of images in divs that i'm trying to call by their data attribute. What I want to do is find out if the img tag has a data attribute called "data-source", for now an alert is called. else run the rest of my code.

HTML:

```
        <div class="product_selection">
            <div class="product_details">
                <img data-source="Companies" src="/images/img_01.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details">
                <img data-source="Companies" src="/images/img_02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details">
                <img data-source="Companies" src="/images/img_03.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product_details">
                <img  src="/images/img_04.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

script:

```
            $('.product_details img').click(function() {
        var mainImg = $('.main_img_switch img');
        var test = $(this).attr('data-source');
        if (test.length > 0) {
            alert("check");
        } else {
            var tempSrc = mainImg.attr("src");
            mainImg.attr("src", this.src);
            this.src = tempSrc;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking about but, why don't you just select them by the data-source attribute? `var imgs = $('img[data-source]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to correct your if statement to:

```
if (test && test.length > 0)
```

Look at your console log (f12) - it shows you the error in your code. Your `test` variable is set to `undefined` because there is no data-source attribute. So, `test.length` is the same as trying to access `undefined.length`, which is an error. You fix it by first checking that test exists, so `test && test.length`.

In this case, `test` will either always be `undefined` or a string, so `if (test)` is a sufficient check that it exists, but a more technically correct check is:

```
if (typeof test === 'string' && test.length)
```